# Multi file assemblies

Tags: .net, assemblies, .net-assembly

What is the difference and advantage between having a single file assembly that is physically coded in multiple .cs files and a multi file assembly that has multiple .NetModules??

My prof says that the difference could be realized when these assemblies get loaded or during jitting. That not all .Netmodules of a multi file assembly will be loaded at once. But even he is not sure. Could anybody clarify me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lets assume that we have two .cs files called 
`RUT.cs`, which contains rarely used types 
`FUT.cs`, which contains frequently used types 
Now `csc /t:module RUT.cs`
This line causes the C# compiler to create a RUT.netmodule file. This file is a standard DLL PE
file, but, by itself, the CLR can’t load it.

Next let’s compile the frequently used types into their own module. We’ll make this module
the keeper of the assembly’s manifest because the types are used so often. In fact, because
this module will now represent the entire assembly, I’ll change the name of the output file to
JeffTypes.dll instead of calling it FUT.dll:

```
csc /out:JeffTypes.dll /t:library /addmodule:RUT.netmodule FUT.cs
```

This line tells the C# compiler to compile the FUT.cs file to produce the JeffTypes.dll file.
Because /t:library is specified, a DLL PE file containing the manifest metadata tables is
emitted into the JeffTypes.dll file. The /addmodule:RUT.netmodule switch tells the compiler
that RUT.netmodule is a file that should be considered part of the assembly. Specifically, the
/addmodule switch tells the compiler to add the file to the FileDef manifest metadata table
and to add RUT.netmodule’s publicly exported types to the ExportedTypesDef manifest
metadata table.
[image]

The RUT.netmodule file contains the IL code generated by compiling RUT.cs. This file also
contains metadata tables that describe the types, methods, fields, properties, events, and so
on that are defined by RUT.cs. The metadata tables also describe the types, methods, and
so on that are referenced by RUT.cs. The JeffTypes.dll is a separate file. Like RUT.netmodule,
this file includes the IL code generated by compiling FUT.cs and also includes similar definition
and reference metadata tables. However, JeffTypes.dll contains the additional manifest
metadata tables, making JeffTypes.dll an assembly. The additional manifest metadata tables
describe all of the files that make up the assembly (the JeffTypes.dll file itself and the
RUT.netmodule file). The manifest metadata tables also include all of the public types
exported from JeffTypes.dll and RUT.netmodule

Now if some clinet code refrencing to JeffTypes.dll is executing,
When a method is called for the first time, the
CLR detects the types that the method references as a parameter, a return value, or as a
local variable. The CLR then attempts to load the referenced assembly’s file that contains the
manifest. If the type being accessed is in this file, the CLR performs its internal bookkeeping,
allowing the type to be used. If the manifest indicates that the referenced type is in a different
file, the CLR attempts to load the necessary file, performs its internal bookkeeping, and
allows the type to be accessed. The CLR loads assembly files only when a method referencing
a type in an unloaded assembly is called.
 **This means that to run an application, all of the files
from a referenced assembly do not need to be present.** 
So, less used source classes could be compiled in NetModules and **loaded when necessary, boosting performance** and **less Dll file sizes** eases **change management and deployment process**.
 

*Images and some of the quotes from* [jeffrey richter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045)